# is there a proper way to handle multiple errors/exceptions?

Tags: oop, exception

in OO programming, is there some conceptual pattern, ideas, about handling multiple errors?

for example, i have a method that performs some checks and should return an error message for each error found

['name is too short', 'name contains invalid unicode sequences', 'name is too long']

now, should i use an array of exceptions (not thrown exceptions)?

or something like this is better:

```
class MyExceptionList extends Exception{
  public Void addException(Exception e){}
  public Array getExceptions(){}
}
```

any theory behind this argument will be appreciated!

(this isn't a request about a specific programming language, but a pure theoretical one)

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, many languages and frameworks (including C++, Java, and .net) use an exception-handling mechanism which requires the *type* of an an exception object to simultaneously answer many questions, including:

1. What happened

   What actions need to be taken beyond stack unwinding

   At what point should the system be considered to be in a "known" state, at least with regard to the problems indicated by the exception.

Unfortunately, while the answers to those questions are somewhat related, they are in reality far from 100% correlated.  Unfortunately, the assumption that the type of an exception will be sufficient to answer all of those questions makes it difficult to deal sensibly with many situations.

If you have control over all the exceptions that can be thrown, it may be helpful to use an exception-handling paradigm where the exception-handling object includes a virtual `IsResolved` property or method along with a `ShouldCatchAs<T>` property or method that returns a `T` if the exception needs to be handled as a `T`.  Such a paradigm would be able to smoothly handle situations where an exception occurs while unwinding the stack from an earlier exception (the existing exception and new one would be wrapped into a composite exception object, whose `ShouldCatchAs` property would combine those of the original exceptions, and whose `IsResolved` property should only return `true` when both of the original exceptions' `IsResolved` properties do likewise).

I don't know any way to integrate such behavior into the existing frameworks unless one catches and wraps all exceptions that don't fit the paradigm, but perhaps future frameworks can facilitate such things.

Answer (score 1):

From my years of experience, dealing with errors is best done via logging them at all levels, and return true/false from functions, indicating success/fail.

Logging is implementation dependant. It could be to a file, to memory, and you can log messages, unique numbers, whatever, as long as the log will enable you to pinpoint the exact place of the error.

I sometimes use exceptions, in cases where I perform many operations, each one depending on the success of its predecessor. This makes the code cleaner, with no `if`s for error checking. Nevertheless, this is not the main thing to care about. The main thing is log the errors, and return success/fail. Success/fail is needed so that you can decide whether to continue the normal way or not (such as not doing the indended operation because the read size may overrun the memory).

Two more important notes:

1) You must construct a super easy API to report (log) your messages, otherwise you will find yourself postponing this crucial thing, eventually not doing it.

2) It's essential for the log or report to be easily viewed and inform you about the problems as they accure. Otherwise you might find yourself not using the error report mechansim at all.

This is a very important subject to me, and I believe it to be one of the most important issues in software engineering. You can read more about it on my [website](http://www.codechords.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=56%3areturned-error-codes-what-to-do-with-them&catid=37%3asoftware&Itemid=55)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be throwing `Exception`s then.

An `Exception` is meant for an **exceptional case**. Errors found on a validation method isn't considered "Exceptional", it's rather obvious that validation errors would occur.

An **exceptional** situation is when your attempt to connect to a database failed, for example.

You should log all validation errors to an array, and then format it and display it as you like.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. then how should I handle multiple errors in the same method?

Comment: @toPeerOrNotToPeer: `You should log all validation errors to an array, and then format it and display it as you like.` How was that not clear?

Comment: ahahahaha i'm sorry i've totally missed it. ok.

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions are not intended for validation, they are intended to be created when something that is different from what was expected happens during the execution. This is why you can't create many exceptions at once, but exceptions can be caused because some other exception happened, this is why they can have a parent exception named case.